# How to generically register all udfs from an object in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I want to have an object that holds all my udfs and a trait I can add onto a class and just call registerUDFs and all udf methods from the object will get registered without any manual entry for udf registration. I have some sample code that is all good except for the part with the ???. If anyone can help me fill in this blank, that would be great.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Foo {
  val isEven: UserDefinedFunction = udf((a: Int) => {
    if (a % 2 == 0) true else false
  })
}

trait Bar {
  def registerUDFs(spark: SQLContext) = Foo.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.foreach {
    case method if method.getGenericReturnType == UserDefinedFunction.getClass => spark.udf.register(method.getName, ?????)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if someone has a different way of solving this problem so I don't have to manually register all the udfs I'm making, that would also be an acceptable answer.